# Unable to redirect on javascript button click

Tags: javascript

I am using the below javascript to create a record and redirect to google.com.
On Button click it is unable to redirect it to google.com. Instead the url is becoming like

https://ap1.salesforce.com/www.google.com

And also i am unable to get user info.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var acct = new sforce.SObject("Userinfo__c");
var user = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
acct.LoginTime__c= new Date().toISOString();
acct.User_Name__c = user;
var result = sforce.connection.create([acct]);

if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
window.location="http://www.google.com";
}else{
alert('Could not create record '+result);
}
```

Comment: try with window.open instead window.location

Comment: not working....

Comment: what is the behaviour of the custom button is it open in new page or window try with different that may be causing the issue ?

Comment: try `window.parent.location`

Comment: it is opening in the same page.. even window.parent.location is not working..

Comment: window.open worked...Got userid also..Now i have an issue to get the tab name clicked

Comment: Well, I have used same code `window.parent.location='http://www.google.com'` and it works

Comment: ok abdn.. Thanks .. How to get the tab name clicked..

Comment: Perhaps `window.top.location`?

Comment: try this window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Salesforce has a problem with `window.location`, try `window.location.href` instead.